# State change doesn't trigger rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I've set a MUI Table with its last row containing a few TextFields as such (content stripped for readability) :

```
[Generated rows...]
<TableRow>
  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
    <TextField/>
  </TableCell> ...

  <TableCell>
    <Button variant="outlined" onClick={() => addFond()}>
        <Add />
    </Button>
  </TableCell>
</TableRow>
```

Above rows are to be generated from an Array coming from a persistent storage state.
One row is to be added using the `addFond()` button and function:

```
const addFond = () => {
  userDefaults.assuranceVie ??= {}
  userDefaults.assuranceVie.tableFondsVI ??= []
  userDefaults.assuranceVie.tableFondsVI.push({ ...formik.values, id: uuidv4() })
  setDefaults(userDefaults)
}
```

I'm using a Formik form for the new row, and would like to create a new formik row for all the iterated rows above the last one.

When clicking the `addFond()` button, I expected the state to change and to rerender the whole component.
I have a `console.log` printing the state at top-level of the component, but nothing prints when clicking.

Note that this Table component is embedded into an higher order  tag.

**After resolution edit :**

I couldn't modify the state object and expect the change detection to work after using the setter since the state didn't actually change.

Comment: More info would be appreciated. tell us more about how "top-level" of your console.log placement in the component, and provide a rough structure of the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> State change doesn't trigger rerender

There's no any state change, actually. The re-render is not triggered because the previous value of state is exactly the same as the new one, since you are mutating it.

`userDefaults.assuranceVie ??= {}` -> state mutation.

You should base on the callback function of `setState` to be sure you refer to the current state and you should return a new object to avoid mutation.

```
const addFond = () => {
  setDefaults((prev) => ({
     ...prev,
     assuranceVie: {
        ...(prev.assuranceVie || {}), // in case if not exists
        tableFondsVI: [
           ...(prev.assuranceVie?.tableFondsVI || []), 
           { ...formikValues, id: uuidv4() }
        ],
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: This worked! I didn't know that mutating the state object would interfere with change detection. Thank you.